# NSLayoutConstraint - I want to create side margins

Tags: ios, nslayoutconstraint

I have a view that is in a container

[image]

In some of the view controllers that I place in this container, i want to have global side margins

but I don't know how to add them to the container.

I mean I don't know how to define the NSLayoutConstraint to do what I want.

I want side margins of 20pts from each side, left and right of the container, in regards to its superview

Answer (score 1):

It should look something like that:

```
// Get  view and bind that
UIView * view = childViewController.view;
NSDictionary *views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(view); // @"view" : view
// add constraint to view with margins - -value- to supertview - | in horizontal axis
[view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-20.0-[view]-20.0-|" options:0 metrics:metrics views:views]];
// The same for vertical axis
[view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-20.0-[view]-20.0-|" options:0 metrics:metrics views:views]];
```

Also, take a look at this tutorial: http://commandshift.co.uk/blog/2013/01/31/visual-format-language-for-autolayout/ . It looks nice.

Good Luck!

Comment: unfortunately this didnt work either, since i am working with containers, it is unclear to me where should i add this code, to make sure it doesnt fall on the fact that childViewController.view does not have a superview on viewdidload

Comment: Why do you need `viewDidLoad`? In order to show you child view controller, you need to `addSubview:`(or `insertSubview`) `childViewController.view` somewhere, so you can perform these code right after `addSubview:`

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this with a more intuitive code than the official API (of which the visual format is the easiest to grasp, but still not very intuitive IMHO).

If you use a third party category like https://github.com/jrturton/UIView-Autolayout (which I recommend you do), this is solved with as little code as this:

```
[yourView pinToSuperviewEdges:JRTViewPinLeftEdge|JRTViewPinRightEdge inset:20.0];
```

**UPDATE**

Since your comment states that the right edge does not work, you can try setting the edge constraints individually to debug it, like this:

```
[yourView pinEdge:NSLayoutAttributeLeft toEdge:NSLayoutAttributeLeft ofView:yourSuperView inset:20];
[yourView pinEdge:NSLayoutAttributeRight toEdge:NSLayoutAttributeRight ofView:yourSuperView inset:40];
```

Change the inset around on the second constraint to see if you get it right. If it suddenly looks right with an inset of 50, you know that the superview is too wide (by 30 pixels in this case).

Comment: the left edge seems to work, but the right edge, makes the views get cut off, what do i need to do to fix this ?

Comment: Added example of setting them individually, so that you can try to debug what is "wrong" with the right edge inset.

Comment: What is the super view, and how is it sized?